# where is mapping table of Id and it's role stored?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, authorization, windows-authentication

I'm using asp.net core authorization.I have some roles like 
 SuperAdmin ,Admin,User. Each user will be assigned one of them. SuperAdmin can change the role of any user.So basically i want dynamic role system.
So where to map user-Role data and

> [Authorize(Roles = "Admin")]

goes where to check the role of user?
means where this thing checks the role.

> I'm using Windows Authentication

Comment: Sounds like to you want to use Claims-based authorization not Windows authorization.

Comment: im not able to find where role-user is mapped . I mentioned windows authentication bcs there is no username password table maintained in my database. @mr.coffee

Comment: These are all basic ASP.Net identity functions. Plenty documentation, for instance https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/roles?view=aspnetcore-3.0.

Answer (score 0):

You can use claims-based authorization via policies . After setting windows authentication in your application , you could add custom claim to ClaimsPrincipal ,check user's identity and confirm which permission/role the current user has :

1. You can add a claims transformation service to your application:

   ```
   class ClaimsTransformer : IClaimsTransformation
   {
       public Task<ClaimsPrincipal> TransformAsync(ClaimsPrincipal principal)
       {
           var id = ((ClaimsIdentity)principal.Identity);

           var ci = new ClaimsIdentity(id.Claims, id.AuthenticationType, id.NameClaimType, id.RoleClaimType);

           //read database or flies or query AD to confirm user role by use ci.Name(username)
           if (....)
           {
               ci.AddClaim(new Claim("role", "Admin"));
           }
           else
           {
               ci.AddClaim(new Claim("role", "user"));

           }


           var cp = new ClaimsPrincipal(ci);

           return Task.FromResult(cp);
       }
   }
   ```
2. Add to Startup.cs :

   ```
       services.AddAuthentication(IISDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
       services.AddTransient<IClaimsTransformation, ClaimsTransformer>();
   ```
3. Set your policy :

   ```
       services.AddAuthorization(options =>
       {
           options.AddPolicy("Admin", policy =>
                             policy.RequireClaim("role", "Admin"));

           options.AddPolicy("User", policy =>
                           policy.RequireClaim("role", "user"));
       });
   ```
4. Restrict access to a controller or action by requiring this policy:

   ```
       [Authorize(Policy = "Admin")]
       public IActionResult Contact()
       {
          .....
       }
   ```

You can also use AD groups as roles . Base on your requirement , you can modify above codes to fit your scenario . Manage user/roles could use local database or ASP.NET Core Identity auto-create tables.

Comment: But where to see which user holds which role . Where this data is stored?

Comment: role claim is add to cookie , that up to you to store in somewhere , for example ,database .

Comment: exactly thats what i want. I want to store role in database so that i can manage that dynamically . so how to store them in database

Comment: You can in `IClaimsTransformation` service to read role/group from AD and save to database , or anywhere in specific action to perform the role management , that up to you . Not sure what's your question.

Comment: in my app superadmin will decide the role of every user . By default role is "employee".i want to give capability to super admin that he can change role of any user.in future new roles can be introduced. so i want database table where role of perticula user is mapped . on that table i can perform update for role change of any user

Comment: Ok , so local database is used for manage user/roles . Then as above reply shows , you can read database in  `transformation` service and add claim to user's  ClaimsPrincipal . Then you can check roles in your whole application .

Comment: and where to put this claims transformation service ?

Comment: see my code sample , it is registered in DI system , it will trigger after windows authentication .